# How to call OriginalDocuments form by code D365fo

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, x++, dynamics-365

Hi I am trying to call the `OriginalDocuments` form like the `LedgerVoucherTrans` calls it but from a different form (custom), I am trying it by calling the `menuitem` passing the `GeneralJournalAccountEntry` table as record argument but when I debug it I look than the method `linkactive` for the `tmpledgerbase` `datasource` didn't reach.

my clicked method for the button where I call it:

```
public void clicked()
{
generalJournalAccountEntry general;
MenuFunction    menuFunction;
Args args = new Args();

general = 
  generalJournalAccountEntry::find(PWFindWrongAnalyticalCodeValuesQuery.GeneralRecId);

args.record(general);
args.caller(this);

menuFunction = new MenuFunction(menuItemDisplayStr(Originaldocuments), MenuItemType::Display);
menuFunction.run(args);
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: But does the Originaldocuments form open?